# HTML email body with embedded local image

Tags: python, outlook, html-email, pywin32, office-automation

I was trying to automate a email sending process. This email was supposed to have a image on its body. In the code below, I've put the image on the email html body. Since the image path is at my local machine, the recipients would not receive it on the email body, and it would only appear in the case that the email was sent to myself.
Anyone here would know how to fix this issue?

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

recipients = 'example@gmail.com'

cropped_image = r'C:\\Users\\Antonio_Ravazzolo\\PycharmProjects\\AutomationDFS\\cropped_screenshot.png'

mail.To = recipients
mail.Subject = 'subject'
mail.HTMLBody = r'<img src="C:\\Users\\Antonio_Ravazzolo\\PycharmProjects\\AutomationDFS\\cropped_screenshot.png">'\
                '<p>Feel free to contact me in case you have any questions/doubts.<p>'\
                '<p>Regards, Antônio Ravazzolo.<p>'


mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"`) using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` and refer that attachment through the `src` attribute that matches the value of `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` set on the attachment:

```
attachment = MailItem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId1")
MailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:MyId1""></body></html>"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to *attach an image* to the mail item and use the `cid` notation in the message to refer to the embedded image in the HTML markup.

```
mail.Attachments.Add "D:\ImageFile.img", olByValue, 0
sImgName = "ImageFile.img" 
mail.HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:" & sImgName & "'" & " ><br>"
```

Otherwise, the local path make sense only to your machine:

```
cropped_image = r'C:\\Users\\Antonio_Ravazzolo\\PycharmProjects\\AutomationDFS\\cropped_screenshot.png'
```

There is no such path on the recipient, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are the only person who accesses the image path, and on that path, you have an image.
There is no path on other computers as if you pass it through the email in others computer.
you can solve it by :

1- you can save the image in the `static` folder. (if you use the Flask or Django as backend)

2- or upload it on the cloud and give access from there.

3- pass the image on the attachment